# How do I use an Azure Logic App to request an OAUTH access token?

Tags: azure, rest, azure-logic-apps

Within Postman, using the form-data option, I am able to successfully request an access token from the [Petfinder API](https://www.petfinder.com/developers/v2/docs/) (see screenshot 1) but I am unable to reproduce this in an Azure Logic App

Screenshot 1

[image: Access Token through Petfinder API in Azure Logic App]

I have tried using the following HTTP action in Azure Logic Apps, with and without the Headers populated. (see screenshots 2 and 3)

Screenshot 2
[image: Azure Logic App Petfinder API Access Token]
Screenshot 3
[image: Pet Finder Access Token Bad Request]

This is the error message I get back in the output

```
    "body": {
        "type": "https://httpstatus.es/400",
        "status": 400,
        "title": "unsupported_grant_type",
        "detail": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "code": "unsupported_grant_type",
                "title": "Unauthorized",
                "message": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server. - Check that all required parameters have been provided",
                "details": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server. - Check that all required parameters have been provided",
                "href": "http://developer.petfinder.com/v2/errors.html#unsupported_grant_type"
            }
        ],
        "hint": "Check that all required parameters have been provided"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the issue at my environment using URL** `Post https://login.microsoft.com/tenant_id/oauth2/token` as I can't create account in `https://www.petfinder.com/developers/v2/docs/` due to country limitation but the process of getting the token is similar in both the cases.

**My workflow looks like below**-

[image]

In **When a HTTP request request is received** trigger, I am taking the below schema.

```
{
"properties": {
"client_id": {
"type": "string"
},
"client_secret": {
"type": "string"
},
"tenant_id": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"type": "object"
}
```

Then I have added **HTTP** to get the bearer token.
**Please note**, here `Content-Type = multipart/form-data; boundary=--boundary` and **request body is in this format**

```
----boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grant_type"

client_credentials
----boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_id"

your client_id
----boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_secret"

your client_secret
----boundary--
```

[image]
[image]

Then added **Data Operation - Parse JSON action**, using the following schema

```
{
"properties": {
"access_token": {
"type": "string"
},
"expires_in": {
"type": "string"
},
"expires_on": {
"type": "string"
},
"ext_expires_in": {
"type": "string"
},
"not_before": {
"type": "string"
},
"resource": {
"type": "string"
},
"token_type": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"type": "object"
}
```

**Trigger Output**-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**For Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

[image]

**Test Result**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My workflow is a little different with "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--boundary". Am I using the wrong boundary parameter?

Comment: "HTTP_GET_TOKEN": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=@{body('Get_secret_PetFinderApiKey')?['value']}&client_secret=@{body('Get_secret_PetFinderApiSecret')?['value']}",
                    "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--boundary"
                    },
                    "method": "POST",
                    "uri": "https://api.petfinder.com/v2/oauth2/token"
                }

Comment: I have modified my answer, please check

Comment: Will you post the picture of your original answer as that would be very helpful for another API I am working on. This works like a dream

Comment: added the screenshot